# jHeatmap Javascript library tab behaves strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been struggling with this problem for days and it really baffled me.  Hopefully someone skillful in JQuery could help out.

This is related to a very powerful and nice javascript library for creating interactive heatmaps.  http://jheatmap.github.io/jheatmap/.  I am modifying one of the examples -- Quickstart -- in order to display more than one heatmap on a page.  The idea is to put heatmap on separate tabs and activate a heatmap by clicking on a particular tab.  The tool couldn't do this naturally, instead it only displays one heatmap on each html page.  The developer suggested a solution but here is the problem.

In this sample code, I intend to display three heatmaps (call them heatmap1, heatmap2 and heatmap3) on three tabs.  The current situation is that I must click on heatmap1's tab first before clicking on tabs for heatmap2 or heatmap3.  Since heatmap1 is displayed by default, so when the page is initially up, I can just go ahead to click on tab's for heatmap2 and that is fine.  But now if I want to display heatmap3, I must go back to click on heatmap1's tab, then click on heatmap3's tab.  After I manage to see heatmap3 using this trick, I will need to click on heatmap1's tab again in order to display heatmap2.  It seems heatmap1 must be displayed before any other heatmaps to be shown.

Since my account won't allow me to attach a file, I put the code below.  This is a direct modification of the Jheatmap's QuickStart step4 code.  You will not be able to run it because the script loads/reads in text files.  But I would greatly appreciate if you can take a look at the javascript around the three heatmaps and the html codes rendering the objects.  I think someone skillful in JQuery could give me some advice on how to fix the bug.

Thanks much for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jHeatmap</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="../../styles/jheatmap-1.0.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <style>
            /* To center the heatmap */
        table.heatmap {
            margin: 0px auto;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/jheatmap-1.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

         /* heatmap1 */
         $('#heatmap1').heatmap(
            {
                data: {
                    rows: new jheatmap.readers.AnnotationReader({ url: "quickstart-rows.tsv" }),
                    cols: new jheatmap.readers.AnnotationReader({ url: "quickstart-cols.tsv" }),
                    values: new jheatmap.readers.TableHeatmapReader({ url: "quickstart-data.tsv" })
                },

                init: function (heatmap) {

                    // Column annotations
                    heatmap.cols.decorators["subtype2"] = new jheatmap.decorators.CategoricalRandom();
                    heatmap.cols.annotations = ["subtype"];

                    // Rows annotations
                    heatmap.rows.decorators["fm-bias"] = new jheatmap.decorators.PValue({ cutoff: 0.05 });
                    heatmap.rows.annotations = ["fm-bias"];

                    // Aggregators
                    heatmap.cells.aggregators["Mutation"] = new jheatmap.aggregators.AbsoluteAddition();
                    heatmap.cells.aggregators["CNA Status"] = new jheatmap.aggregators.AbsoluteAddition();
                    heatmap.cells.aggregators["Expression"] = new jheatmap.aggregators.Median();

                    // Decorators
                    heatmap.cells.decorators["Mutation"] = new jheatmap.decorators.Categorical({
                                    values: ["0","1"],
                                    colors : ["white","green"]
                    });

                    heatmap.cells.decorators["CNA Status"] = new jheatmap.decorators.Categorical({
                                    values: ["-2","2"],
                                    colors : ["blue","red"]
                    });

                    heatmap.cells.decorators["Expression"] = new jheatmap.decorators.Heat({
                                    minValue: -2,
                                    midValue: 0,
                                    maxValue: 2,
                                    minColor: [85, 0, 136],
                                    nullColor: [255,255,255],
                                    maxColor: [255, 204, 0],
                                    midColor: [240,240,240]
                    });

                }
            });

         /* heatmap2 */
         $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).tab('show');

                // Load Heatmap2 
                if ($(this).tab()[0].hash == '#heatmap2Tab') {
                    $('#heatmap-loader').show();
                    $('#heatmap2').width($('#heatmap').width());
                    $('#heatmap2').heatmap(
                    {
                        data: {
                            rows: new jheatmap.readers.AnnotationReader({ url: "quickstart-rows.tsv" }),
                            cols: new jheatmap.readers.AnnotationReader({ url: "quickstart-cols.tsv" }),
                            values: new jheatmap.readers.TableHeatmapReader({ url: "quickstart-data.tsv" })
                        },

                        init: function (heatmap) {

                            // Column annotations
                            heatmap.cols.decorators["subtype"] = new jheatmap.decorators.CategoricalRandom();
                            heatmap.cols.annotations = ["subtype"];

                            // Rows annotations
                            heatmap.rows.decorators["fm-bias"] = new jheatmap.decorators.PValue({ cutoff: 0.05 });
                            heatmap.rows.annotations = ["fm-bias"];

                            // Aggregators
                            heatmap.cells.aggregators["Mutation"] = new jheatmap.aggregators.AbsoluteAddition();
                            heatmap.cells.aggregators["CNA Status"] = new jheatmap.aggregators.AbsoluteAddition();
                            heatmap.cells.aggregators["Expression"] = new jheatmap.aggregators.Median();

                            // Decorators
                            heatmap.cells.decorators["Mutation"] = new jheatmap.decorators.Categorical({
                                            values: ["0","1"],
                                            colors : ["white","green"]
                            });

                            heatmap.cells.decorators["CNA Status"] = new jheatmap.decorators.Categorical({
                                            values: ["-2","2"],
                                            colors : ["blue","red"]
                            });

                            heatmap.cells.decorators["Expression"] = new jheatmap.decorators.Heat({
                                            minValue: -2,
                                            midValue: 0,
                                            maxValue: 2,
                                            minColor: [85, 0, 136],
                                            nullColor: [255,255,255],
                                            maxColor: [255, 204, 0],
                                            midColor: [240,240,240]
                            });

                        }
                    });
                }

          })

         /* heatmap3 */
         $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             $(this).tab('show');

             // Load Heatmap2 
             if ($(this).tab()[0].hash == '#heatmap3Tab') {
                 $('#heatmap-loader').show();
                 $('#heatmap3').width($('#heatmap').width());
                 $('#heatmap3').heatmap(
                 {
                     data: {
                         rows: new jheatmap.readers.AnnotationReader({ url: "quickstart-rows.tsv" }),
                         cols: new jheatmap.readers.AnnotationReader({ url: "quickstart-cols.tsv" }),
                         values: new jheatmap.readers.TableHeatmapReader({ url: "quickstart-data.tsv" })
                     },

                     init: function (heatmap) {

                         // Column annotations
                         heatmap.cols.decorators["subtype"] = new jheatmap.decorators.CategoricalRandom();
                         heatmap.cols.annotations = ["subtype"];

                         // Rows annotations
                         heatmap.rows.decorators["fm-bias"] = new jheatmap.decorators.PValue({ cutoff: 0.05 });
                         heatmap.rows.annotations = ["fm-bias"];

                         // Aggregators
                         heatmap.cells.aggregators["Mutation"] = new jheatmap.aggregators.AbsoluteAddition();
                         heatmap.cells.aggregators["CNA Status"] = new jheatmap.aggregators.AbsoluteAddition();
                         heatmap.cells.aggregators["Expression"] = new jheatmap.aggregators.Median();

                         // Decorators
                         heatmap.cells.decorators["Mutation"] = new jheatmap.decorators.Categorical({
                             values: ["0", "1"],
                             colors: ["white", "green"]
                         });

                         heatmap.cells.decorators["CNA Status"] = new jheatmap.decorators.Categorical({
                             values: ["-2", "2"],
                             colors: ["blue", "red"]
                         });

                         heatmap.cells.decorators["Expression"] = new jheatmap.decorators.Heat({
                             minValue: -2,
                             midValue: 0,
                             maxValue: 2,
                             minColor: [85, 0, 136],
                             nullColor: [255, 255, 255],
                             maxColor: [255, 204, 0],
                             midColor: [240, 240, 240]
                         });

                     }
                 });
             }

         })


    });</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><a href="step0.html">Step 0</a></li>
            <li><a href="step1.html">Step 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="step2.html">Step 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="step3.html">Step 3</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="step4.html">Step 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="step5.html">Step 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
           Add column and row annotation headers.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="heatmap-loader">
            <div class="background"></div>
            <div class="loader">
                <img src="../../images/loading.gif">
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#heatmap1Tab" data-toggle="tab">Heatmap1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#heatmap2Tab" data-toggle="tab">Heatmap2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#heatmap3Tab" data-toggle="tab">Heatmap3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#javascriptTab" data-toggle="tab">Javascript</a></li>
            <li><a href="#dataTab" data-toggle="tab">quickstart-data.tsv</a></li>
            <li><a href="#cdataTab" data-toggle="tab">quickstart-cols.tsv</a></li>
            <li><a href="#rdataTab" data-toggle="tab">quickstart-rows.tsv</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="heatmap1Tab" style="">
                <div id="heatmap1"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="heatmap2Tab" style="">
                <div id="heatmap2" style="width:100%;"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="heatmap3Tab" style="">
                <div id="heatmap3" style="width:100%;"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="javascriptTab">
                <pre id="source" class="prettyprint linenums"></pre>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dataTab">
                <pre id="data" class="prettyprint"></pre>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="cdataTab">
                <pre id="cdata" class="prettyprint"></pre>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="rdataTab">
                <pre id="rdata" class="prettyprint"></pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var source = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[2].innerHTML;
    source = source.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    $('#source').html(source);
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();

    $('#source ol.linenums li').each(function(idx, li) {
        if ((idx > 3 && idx < 6) || (idx > 10 && idx < 18)) {
            $(li).css("background-color", "#FFFFB3");
        }
    });

    jQuery.ajax({

        url: "quickstart-data.tsv",

        dataType: "text",

        success: function (file) {
            $('#data').html(file);
        }
    });

    jQuery.ajax({

        url: "quickstart-cols.tsv",

        dataType: "text",

        success: function (file) {
            $('#cdata').html(file);
        }
    });

    jQuery.ajax({

        url: "quickstart-rows.tsv",

        dataType: "text",

        success: function (file) {
            $('#rdata').html(file);
        }
    });

</script>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-7336589-2', 'jheatmap.github.io');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the main problem in your code is that you are binding two functions to all the click tab events. You only need to bind one function and this function will draw only one heatmap depending on the link that was clicked.

Here you have a simplified version that draws three heatmaps on different tabs:

```
<html>
 <head>
     <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="http://jheatmap.github.io/jheatmap/css/jheatmap-1.0.0-min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
     <script src="http://jheatmap.github.io/jheatmap/js/jheatmap-1.0.0-min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script>  
     var draw_heatmap = function (tag_id) {
                $('#'+tag_id).heatmap({
                data: {
                    values: new jheatmap.readers.TableHeatmapReader({ url: "http://jheatmap.github.io/jheatmap/examples/quickstart/quickstart-data.tsv" })
                }});        
     };

     $(document).ready(function () {

         /* Draw the default visible heatmap */
         draw_heatmap('heatmap1');

         /* Calculate the visible heatmap width */
         var heatmap_width = $('#heatmap1').width();

         /* Fix the width to all the heatmaps */
         $('#heatmap1').width(heatmap_width);
         $('#heatmap2').width(heatmap_width);
         $('#heatmap3').width(heatmap_width);

         /* Attach draw heatmap to tab click event */
         $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                /* Show the clicked tab */
                $(this).tab('show');

                /* Show the loader indicator */
                $('#heatmap-loader').show();

                /* Draw the correct heatmap */
                if ($(this).tab()[0].hash == '#heatmap1Tab') {
                    draw_heatmap('heatmap1');
                }

                if ($(this).tab()[0].hash == '#heatmap2Tab') {
                    draw_heatmap('heatmap2');
                }

                if ($(this).tab()[0].hash == '#heatmap3Tab') {
                    draw_heatmap('heatmap3');
                }
          });
    });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>    
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="heatmap-loader">
            <div class="background"></div>
            <div class="loader">
                <img src="http://jheatmap.github.io/jheatmap/images/loading.gif">
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#heatmap1Tab" data-toggle="tab">Heatmap1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#heatmap2Tab" data-toggle="tab">Heatmap2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#heatmap3Tab" data-toggle="tab">Heatmap3</a></li>           
        </ul>
        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="heatmap1Tab">
                <div id="heatmap1"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="heatmap2Tab">
                <div id="heatmap2"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="heatmap3Tab">
                <div id="heatmap3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Jordeu:  Thanks a lot for the excellent answer.  It appears the default heatmap (heatmap1) is very similar to the heatmap2 and heatmap3.  However, if I add some controls in the draw_heatmap function, the controls only work in the default heatmap, not in heatmap2.  Any insight regarding the difference among the three heatmaps?  Thanks much.

Comment: Here is what I mean:  Add the following code into draw_heatmap()

Comment: init: function (heatmap) {
                    $('#hideSelectedBtn').click(function (e) {
                        action = new jheatmap.actions.HideSelected(heatmap);
                        action.columns();
                    });
                    $('#showHiddenBtn').click(function (e) {
                        action = new jheatmap.actions.ShowHidden(heatmap);
                        action.columns();
                    });
                }